# EXTJS 4 - Grid Filter or store filter clearing existing filter on store

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have come across an issue where the grid filter is clearing the existing filter that is on the store.

Basically, I have two grids on top of each other, when a user clicks on the top grid, data is filtered into the second grid, it is the second grid where the issue is occurring.

I have created a simplified example of the issue via fiddle

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/if0

**Notes**

The caveat is that I am "flattening"  nested JSON custom fields via the record.beginEdit() command so that this data can be shown in the grid.   I am using `remoteFilter: false`, if this is set to `remoteFilter: true` then the filter part works but `remoteFilter: true` destroys the nested data set via the `record.beginEdit();`

**How to reproduce**

1) If you apply the grid filter above in column `Name` and select `Homer` then the Grid filter is clearing down the filter applied on the store in line 113 and now showing the two Homer records.  There are two Homer records but each has a different summaryId value.

```
store.filter([{id: 'summaryId', property: 'summaryId', value:1, exactMatch: true}]);
```

2) If you deselect the filter, then the filter applied to the store in line 113 is not maintained and all records are now shown.

Comment: There are two 'Homer' in your data, different emails though

Comment: Kevin, Thanks for responding.  I updated my post,  there are two Homer records in my JSON, both have different summaryId values, the filter is for summaryId 1 only, yet by selecting Homer in the grid filter is causing the store filter to be removed.

Comment: How would I get logs to see the duplicates on Sencha Fiddle

Comment: I am not following, can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: why don't you use local false, instead local filtering in your FilterFeature ?
so, you can filter the data from url dynamically... ?
Or, you create a Filterable for column "summaryId" for your need ?

Comment: By setting local:false is causing my record.set data not to persist.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by " you create a Filterable for column "summaryId" ...thanks.

Comment: Don't worry about it

Comment: Thank You, this gets  me closer  but the filter would need to be dynamically set as the user will click on the top grid resulting in the second grid getting filtered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your store like this below :

```
store = Ext.create('Filter.data.Store', {
    data: data,
    filters: [{
        property: 'summaryId',
        value: '1'
    }]
});
```

Check [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/if1) demo from your previous demo...

**EDIT :**
Try this code to your fiddle, this is a freaky complicated way to get this. so, you need a trigger to filter like a button, may be this will get you a little help. I've edited my Demo Too, check it out.

```
/*global Ext:false */
Ext.Loader.setPath({

});

Ext.require(['*', 'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature']);

Ext.define('Filter.data.Store', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    id: 'simpsonsStore',
    autoLoad: true,
    remoteFilter: false,
    fields: [{
        name: 'name'
    }, {
        name: 'email'
    }, {
        name: 'phone'
    }, {
        name: 'summaryId'
    }, {
        name: 'customFields'
    }, {
        name: 'customFieldId129'
    }, {
        name: 'customFieldId130'
    }],
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});


Ext.onReady(function() {

    var filters = {
        ftype: 'filters',
        encode: false,
        local: true
    };

    data = {
        "total": 5,
        "items": [{
            'id': 1,
            'summaryId': 1,
            'name': 'Lisa',
            "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-222-1234",
            "customFields": [{
                "customFieldId": 129, // there can be multiple customfields
                "customFieldValue": "Bob"
            }, {
                "customFieldId": 130, // there can be multiple customfields
                "customFieldValue": "Smith"
            }, ]
        }, {
            'id': 2,
            'summaryId': 1,
            'name': 'Bart',
            "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-222-1244",
            "customFields": []
        }, {
            'id': 3,
            'summaryId': 1,
            'name': 'Homer',
            "email": "home@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-222-1244",
            "customFields": []
        }, {
            'id': 4,
            'summaryId': 2,
            'name': 'Fred',
            "email": "fred@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-222-1264",
            "customFields": []
        }, {
            'id': 5,
            'summaryId': 2,
            'name': 'Homer',
            "email": "HomerWork@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-222-1264",
            "customFields": []
        }]
    },

    store = Ext.create('Filter.data.Store', {
        data: data,
        //filters: [{
        //    property: 'summaryId',
        //    value: '1'
        //}]
    });

    store.load({
        callback: function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < store.data.length; i++) {
                var record = store.getAt(i);
                var customFieldsData = record.data.customFields;
                if (customFieldsData.length > 0) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < customFieldsData.length; j++) {
                        record.beginEdit();
                        store.filter([{property: 'summaryId',value: '1'}]);
                        record.set('customFieldId' + customFieldsData[j].customFieldId, customFieldsData[j].customFieldValue);
                        record.endEdit(true);
                    }
                }
                //store.sync();
            }
        }
    });

    // apply custom fields
    // the custom field code is an example, in short , nested data
    // and need to use the record function for each record so that the
    // grid can see the record


    //store.filter([{property: 'summaryId',value: '1'}]);
    var btn = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'Click me For filter summaryId',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        handler: function() {
            if(store.isFiltered()){
                //var data = Ext.encode(grid.filters.getFilterData());
                var data1 = grid.filters.getFilterData();
                store.filter([{property: 'summaryId',value: '1'}]);
                store.filter([{property: data1[0].field,value: data1[0].data.value}]);
                //Ext.Msg.alert('All Filter Data',data1[0].field + " " + data1[0].data.value);
                //Ext.Msg.alert('All Filter Data',data);
            }
        }
    });

    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        xtype: 'gridpanel',
        title: 'filter is on summaryId 1 - Selecting Homer returns two records instead of one',
        store: store,
        features: [filters],
        columns: [{
            header: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            filter: {
                type: 'list',
                options: ['Homer']
            }
        }, {
            header: 'summaryId',
            dataIndex: 'summaryId'
        }, {
            header: 'customField1',
            dataIndex: 'customFieldId129' //hardcoded for fiddler example
        }, {
            header: 'customField2',
            dataIndex: 'customFieldId130' //hardcoded for fiddler example
        }],
        width: 700,
        height: 500,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks...that does work but I have two grids on top of each other for my real app, when a user clicks on the top grid, data is filtered into the second grid.  Lets say the user goes back and clicks on a different row on the top grid,  how do I insure that I can change the filter value without having to reload the store and performing a record.beginEdit() again...

Comment: if you want to create like a master-detail grid that need filter params from the top grid to pass on your second grid you need to use method of store.
but the consequences is your problem like this.

I suggest you use an local:false (filtering using ajax to point your need) instead using Loca:true filtering....

Comment: Eko,  if I am understanding you clearly, you are suggesting that I get the server to filter the data and send back to the client...sorry for all the silly questions.

Comment: Yes, sorry for my bad english...
so you just get store data from a previous filter.

Comment: Eko,  you have nothing to apologize for :)...thank you for the input...my problem would be solved if there was some way to persist the data in record.beginEdit(), then I could use remoteFilter:true.

Comment: try using listeners to your store to event "filterchange" to persist the data. from previous filter.

Comment: Check my edited answer, for a tricky way. a little complicated way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71226/discussion-between-user2574678-and-eko-junaidi-salam).

Comment: OK, let us discuss this. But not now, I'm on the way to the hospital to see my sick oldman. Remind me tomorrow...

Comment: Sorry to hear about your oldman, I hope he has a speedy recovery.

Comment: Eko,  in the end I flattened the JSON custom data in the AJAX responsetext,  this turned out be the easiest option.  Thank you for your help, hope all is well.